# CentOS 6 unzip file but files are going to root folder instead

Tags: linux, centos, centos6

When I did

```
unzip /var/www/html/web.zip
```

It unzipped the zip to /root/ folder.
I need it to unzip the files to /var/www/html/

why is it happening?

CentOS 6.3 64bit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do:

```
cd /var/www/html/
unzip web.zip
```

Comment: No problem, you can mark the question as correct now if you're happy with it.

Answer (score 14):

try this:

```
unzip /var/www/html/web.zip -d /var/www/html/
```

your command extracts the archive content to the current directory. you can check if your in /root using the following command

```
pwd
```

Answer (score 0):

To learn more about unzip, you can try running below command. this will return you all options possible with `unzip`

`unzip -man`